# Cumulative count cut with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, count, postgresql-9.1, cumulative-sum

Is there a possibility to realize a cumulative count cut of 2.0 - 98.0% in PostgreSQL?

That means only to select the data range set from 2% until 98%.

Comment: Percent of number of rows total?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the window function [`ntile()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, ntile(50) OVER (ORDER BY ts) AS part
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  ts >= $start
   AND    ts <  $end
   ) sub
WHERE part NOT IN (1, 50);
```

`ts` being your `date` column.

`ntile()` assigns integer numbers to the rows dividing them into the number of partitions specified. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html)

> integer ranging from 1 to the argument value, dividing the partition as equally as possible

By using 50 partitions the first partition matches the first 2 % as closely as possible and the last the last 2 % (> 98%).

**Note**, if there are less than 50 rows the assigned numbers never go up to 50. In this case the first row would be trimmed but not the last. Since the first and last 2 % are not well defined with such a low number of rows this may be considered correct or incorrect. Check for the total number of rows and adapt to your needs. For instance by trimming the last row, too. Or none at all.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your query entirely. I want to hold off the values from a query that are smaller than 2% and bigger than 98% of the cumulative values. I know this from GIS for setting the min, max values for visualizing raster data, for example. Can you give an example?

Comment: @StefanB.: I *did* give an example. And an explanation. Now try the query with your data. It's your job to provide a test case if you need one.